# Data Type Mismatch expression on ms-access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

When i run the query below, i get the error ‘Data type mismatch'

```
SELECT [Hitopathology Table].HospNo, [Hitopathology Table].RecNo, [Hitopathology Table].Name, [Hitopathology Table].Age, [Hitopathology Table].Sex, [Hitopathology Table].Diagnosis, [Hitopathology Table].ReportDate, [Drs List].Surname, [Hospital List].[Hospital Name], [Hitopathology Table].Comments
FROM [Hospital List]
INNER JOIN ([Drs List]
INNER JOIN [Hitopathology Table]
ON [Drs List].DrNo = [Hitopathology Table].DrNo)
ON [Hospital List].HospNo = [Hitopathology Table].HospNo;
```

Answer (score 1):

check the data type each column around the join if they are the same...
`INNER JOIN [Hitopathology Table] ON [Drs List].DrNo = [Hitopathology Table].DrNo) ON [Hospital List].HospNo = [Hitopathology Table].HospNo;`

Comment: Thanks J Zend  ,i had data type mismatch on DrNo on Drs List  and Hitopathology Table.